# Delete all objects in Android Parse local datastore

Tags: android, parse-platform

My Android app reads data from a Parse server. All classes have an "isDeleted" boolean column that determines whether or not the object is considered "live" and should be displayed on the client devices.

Unfortunately, a colleague was asked to delete two objects of a class and he didn't know the proper way to mark the objects as deleted. Instead, he did a hard delete of the two objects on the server. Now these two "zombie" objects won't disappear from the local installs.

I thought that I would be able to fix the issue by deleting all local data from the devices and doing a full data refresh from the server. I wrote an app update that, on detecting a new version number, unpins all objects from the local Parse datastore and re-downloads all data from the server.

```
ParseObject.unpinAll(MyClass.CLASS_NAME);
```

But this line of code doesn't do what I expected it to do. The two objects that were deleted from the server are not deleted from client devices!

How can I completely, thoroughly delete all pinned objects from the local Parse data store and make these two "zombie" objects go away?

The app is using the latest version of Parse:

```
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'
compile 'com.parse:parseui-login-android:0.0.1'
compile 'com.parse:parseui-widget-android:0.0.1'
compile 'com.parse:parseinterceptors:0.0.2'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution to my own question. To delete all objects from the local store, I replaced the call to `ParseObject.unpinAll()` with `ParseObject.unpinAllInBackground()`.

So instead of

```
ParseObject.unpinAll(MyClass.CLASS_NAME)
```

I have

```
ParseObject.unpinAllInBackground(new DeleteCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            // ...
        }
    });
```

Now all the previously saved objects are gone from the local store.

Comment: Do you know if this is expected behavior or a bug in Parse sdk?